# BreakPoint Not Hitting using GN in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ninja, gn

I am using Visual Studio to build and debug my project but while debugging I am getting error that **the breakpoint not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded.**

I have the following things in my project.

Main.cpp:-

```
int GetNumber()
{
int a=0,b=1;
return a+b;
}


int main()
{

std::string str="Hello";
std::cout<<str;
std::cout<< GetNumber();
getchar();
}
```

Also, I have been using the toolchain from gn website- https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/+/HEAD/examples/simple_build

BUILD.gn:-

```
# Copyright 2014 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.

config("compiler_defaults") {
  if (current_os == "linux") {
    cflags = [
      "-fPIC",
      "-pthread",
    ]
  }
}

config("executable_ldconfig") {
  if (!is_mac) {
    ldflags = [
      "-Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN/",
      "-Wl,-rpath-link=",
    ]
  }
}
```

BUILDCONFIG.gn

```
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.

if (target_os == "") {
  target_os = host_os
}
if (target_cpu == "") {
  target_cpu = host_cpu
}
if (current_cpu == "") {
  current_cpu = target_cpu
}
if (current_os == "") {
  current_os = target_os
}

is_linux = host_os == "linux" && current_os == "linux" && target_os == "linux"
is_mac = host_os == "mac" && current_os == "mac" && target_os == "mac"

# All binary targets will get this list of configs by default.
_shared_binary_target_configs = [ "//build:compiler_defaults" ]

# Apply that default list to the binary target types.
set_defaults("executable") {
  configs = _shared_binary_target_configs

  # Executables get this additional configuration.
  configs += [ "//build:executable_ldconfig" ]
}
set_defaults("static_library") {
  configs = _shared_binary_target_configs
}
set_defaults("shared_library") {
  configs = _shared_binary_target_configs
}
set_defaults("source_set") {
  configs = _shared_binary_target_configs
}

set_default_toolchain("//build/toolchain:gcc")
```

BUILD.gn

```
# Copyright 2014 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.

toolchain("gcc") {
  tool("cc") {
    depfile = "{{output}}.d"
    command = "gcc -MMD -MF $depfile {{defines}} {{include_dirs}} {{cflags}} {{cflags_c}} -c {{source}} -o {{output}}"
    depsformat = "gcc"
    description = "CC {{output}}"
    outputs =
        [ "{{source_out_dir}}/{{target_output_name}}.{{source_name_part}}.o" ]
  }

  tool("cxx") {
    depfile = "{{output}}.d"
    command = "g++ -MMD -MF $depfile {{defines}} {{include_dirs}} {{cflags}} {{cflags_cc}} -c {{source}} -o {{output}}"
    depsformat = "gcc"
    description = "CXX {{output}}"
    outputs =
        [ "{{source_out_dir}}/{{target_output_name}}.{{source_name_part}}.o" ]
  }

  tool("alink") {
    command = "rm -f {{output}} && ar rcs {{output}} {{inputs}}"
    description = "AR {{target_output_name}}{{output_extension}}"

    outputs =
        [ "{{target_out_dir}}/{{target_output_name}}{{output_extension}}" ]
    default_output_extension = ".a"
    output_prefix = "lib"
  }

  tool("solink") {
    soname = "{{target_output_name}}{{output_extension}}"  # e.g. "libfoo.so".
    sofile = "{{output_dir}}/$soname"
    rspfile = soname + ".rsp"
    if (is_mac) {
      os_specific_option = "-install_name @executable_path/$sofile"
      rspfile_content = "{{inputs}} {{solibs}} {{libs}}"
    } else {
      os_specific_option = "-Wl,-soname=$soname"
      rspfile_content = "-Wl,--whole-archive {{inputs}} {{solibs}} -Wl,--no-whole-archive {{libs}}"
    }

    command = "g++ -shared {{ldflags}} -o $sofile $os_specific_option @$rspfile"

    description = "SOLINK $soname"

    # Use this for {{output_extension}} expansions unless a target manually
    # overrides it (in which case {{output_extension}} will be what the target
    # specifies).
    default_output_extension = ".so"

    # Use this for {{output_dir}} expansions unless a target manually overrides
    # it (in which case {{output_dir}} will be what the target specifies).
    default_output_dir = "{{root_out_dir}}"

    outputs = [ sofile ]
    link_output = sofile
    depend_output = sofile
    output_prefix = "lib"
  }

  tool("link") {
    outfile = "{{target_output_name}}{{output_extension}}"
    rspfile = "$outfile.rsp"
    if (is_mac) {
      command = "g++ {{ldflags}} -o $outfile @$rspfile {{solibs}} {{libs}}"
    } else {
      command = "g++ {{ldflags}} -o $outfile -Wl,--start-group @$rspfile {{solibs}} -Wl,--end-group {{libs}}"
    }
    description = "LINK $outfile"
    default_output_dir = "{{root_out_dir}}"
    rspfile_content = "{{inputs}}"
    outputs = [ outfile ]
  }

  tool("stamp") {
    command = "touch {{output}}"
    description = "STAMP {{output}}"
  }

  tool("copy") {
    command = "cp -af {{source}} {{output}}"
    description = "COPY {{source}} {{output}}"
  }
}
```

Now, to create the solution file, I am using the following commands:-

```
gn gen --ide=vs out/Default
ninja -C out/Default
```

The solution file is getting generated properly and also the project is building properly but the issue is while hitting breakpoint during debugging.

Comment: The debugger is most likely unable to find the debug symbol file `.pdb` of the executable that you are trying to debug

Comment: @Asesh .pdb is getting generated but still not working. Anything need to be changed in VS settings?